# Search filter in reactjs, say i have an array of data with multiple columns and rows

Tags: reactjs

In the array of each object, theres multiple fields such as name, type, gender, etc...

How would i make a search function based on the name however displays their name, type and gender per column, and filters it per row in reactjs?

```
this.state = {
     Person: [] //This person has Person.name, Person.gender, Person.type etc..
}
```

Comment: Is this.state an Object or an Array?

Comment: It is an array :D

Comment: Depending on your array size, a local database could come in handy. It could provide optimized filter functions and caching/indexing. For example https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways to do that is to create a function that filters your results, store those on your state, and you display them.

```
class People extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // assuming props.people is an array of objects containing name, gender, type, etc.
    const people = props.people;

    this.state = {
      Person: people,
      filteredPerson: people,
    };
  }

  setFilter = (gender) => {
    const uppercaseGender = gender.toUpperCase();
    const filteredPerson = this.state.Person.filter(e =>
      e.gender.toUpperCase().indexOf(uppercaseGender) >= 0
    );

    this.setState({ filteredPerson });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        /* map over this.state.filteredPerson and display the data */
        <button onClick={() => setFilter('male')}>male</button>
        <button onClick={() => setFilter('female')}>female</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the code above, whenever you click the buttons, you'll filter trough the existing list per people and update the state with the new filter value.

You can choose to store the filtering state on the component state as well, if you were to add more filters, for example.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const state = { // would be this.state in your app
    Person: [
        {
            name: "A",
            // gender: "m",
            // ...
        },
        {
            name: "B",
            // gender: "m",
            // ...
        }
    ]
};

const searchTerm = "B";
console.log(state.Person.filter(person => person.name === searchTerm));
```

In your component your render method could be something like this:

```
render() {
    const { Person, searchTerm } = this.state;
    const filteredPerson = !searchTerm.length ? Person : Person.filter(person => person.name === searchTerm);
    const renderedRows = filteredPerson.map(p => <tr key={p.name}><td>{p.name}</td><td>{p.gender}</td><td>{p.type}</td></tr>);

    return <table>{renderedRows}</table>;
}
```

Comment: Would this display the gender, type and name per row ? by filtering it like that

Comment: I added an exemplary render method.

Comment: Maybe you add your component code to get better help.

Comment: Good luck  Keep us informed.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a JS Problem imo, however when using react you can do something like the following:

Note: Since you have not provided any code to work with, I assume you want general direction rather than working code, so you'll have to fill in the gaps.

Basically you are starting with an array of data. You will filter the data based on search. Then you'll turn that array of filtered data in an array of elements and save it to state. In your render function you will render something like `this.state.myElementsArray` and as you change your search criteria and state is updated, your list will automatically update to show the filtered content.

The hardest part, will likely be having a function that fires each time your search box text is changed. For that see how they do it here https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

So The scaffold in your component will be something like this:

```
handleInputChange(e){
    // Here is where you trigger your filter
    this.filterData(query, data);
}

filterData(query, data){
    var filtered_data = data.filter( //Do filtered here );
    this.createElementsArray(filtered_data);
}

createElementsArray(filtered_data){
    var elementsArray = filtered_data.map( (item, index) => {
        return( 
        <tr>
         <td>item.name</td>
         <td>item.job</td>
        </tr>)
    }
    //Now save to state
    this.setState({rows : elementsArray}

}

render(){
   return(
        <div>
        <input className="search-bar" type="text" onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e)}/>
        <table>
           {this.state.rows} //This will show your rows of filtered data
        </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got the idea